# JavaScript - Trying to use two prompts, but they won't pop up

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert, prompt

I know the prompts themselves work, but I'm trying to use one after another to validate a password change, and then run the ajax query to actually change the password and return either a success alert, or a failure alert. The prompts never appear. It's triggered by an onClick event:

```
function pwChange()
    {
        $.modal.prompt('Please Enter Your New Password', function(value)
        {

            if (value === '')
            {
                $(this).getModalContentBlock().message('Please enter a password', { append: false, classes: ['red-gradient'] });
                return false;
            }

        },
        $.modal.prompt('Please Re-Enter Your Password', function(value2)
        {

            if (value2 === '')
            {
                $(this).getModalContentBlock().message('Please re-enter the password', { append: false, classes: ['red-gradient'] });
                return false;
            }
            else if (value2 == value)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'change_password.php',
                    data:"password="+value,
                    success:function(response){
                            if(response=='1'){
                                $.modal.alert('Your password has been changed. Your new password is' + value);
                            }
                            else {
                                $.modal.alert('Unable to Change Password. Please Try Again.');
                            }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        ););
    };
```

Comment: Are you using second prompt as callback to first one?

Comment: Yes I was. Got the answer from @SHIN. I had too many } at the bottom. Thanks! I'd up vote but not enough rep yet.

Comment: Glad you got it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you misplaced "{"

```
function pwChange()
{
$.modal.prompt('Please Enter Your New Password', function(value)
{

    if (value === '')
    {
        $(this).getModalContentBlock().message('Please enter a password', { append: false, classes: ['red-gradient'] });
        return false;
    }


$.modal.prompt('Please Re-Enter Your Password', function(value2)
    {

        if (value2 === '')
        {
            $(this).getModalContentBlock().message('Please re-enter the password', { append: false, classes: ['red-gradient'] });
            return false;
        }
        else if (value2 == value)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'change_password.php',
                data:"password="+value,
                success:function(response){
                        if(response=='1'){
                            $.modal.alert('Your password has been changed. Your new password is' + value);
                        }
                        else {
                            $.modal.alert('Unable to Change Password. Please Try Again.');
                        }
                }
            });
        }
    });





});
};
```